# Upgrading from Gradle 5.1.1 to 6.0.1 breaks Kotlin multiplatform build

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I've upgraded my Kotlin multiplatform project to use Gradle `6.0.1`:

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.0.1 --distribution-type all
```

and now my build is breaking. It doesn't recognize the common modules I add as a dependency to my project:

```
dependencies {
    commonMainApi("mygroup:mylib:$myversion")
}
```

I'm using the Kotlin DSL and this project is also a multiplatform project. What I get is a wall of text detailing all the imports which can't be resolved (all supposed to be imports from a `common` module in my dependency to a `common` module in my project).

The only thing I did was to upgrade to Gradle `6.0.1`. If I restore the previous state my build is OK. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely connected with the fact that Gradle 6.0+ doesn't eagerly request the `*.module` metadata files from a repository unless the `*.pom` of the module contains a special marker, which was absent in `*.pom`s published with older Gradle versions (pre-5.3, I believe)

Those `*.module` metadata files are needed to properly interpret a single dependency as both the common code metadata used to analyze the common sources of your project and the platform-specific artifacts that your targets are built against. Without that, the dependency is resolved to the library's root module which has no artifacts at all.

To fix this on the consumer side, you can make Gradle request those `*.module` metadata files by adding this statement to the repository declaration in your build scripts:

```
repositories {
    jcenter { 
        metadataSources { 
            gradleMetadata()
            mavenPom() 
        }
    }
    // or, if you are using a custom Maven repository:
    maven("https://my.repo.com") { 
        metadataSources { 
            gradleMetadata()
            mavenPom() 
        } 
    }
}
```

In the Gradle docs: [Supported metadata sources](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:supported_metadata_sources)

---

**UPD:** JitPack seems to remove the Gradle module metadata marker (`<!-- do_not_remove: published-with-gradle-metadata -->`) from the POMs, which results in Gradle not requesting `*.module` metadata files. A similar workaround as described above can also be used.

Comment: The library I'm using was published by me today, and it is using Gradle 6.0.1. Does this change anything?

Comment: In other words: what should I do in my other project (I publish) to get this working (which uses 6.0.1)?

Comment: @AdamArold I've never encountered anything like this with libraries published with Gradle 5.3+, so it's not obvious to me why that could happen. Does the root module of your library (the one without a suffix in the name) have the `*.module` file published? Do you specify that module's ID as the dependency? Did you use `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` with Gradle pre-6.0?

Comment: What could also help is the Gradle's dependency insight: `./gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration metadataCompileClasspath --dependency=mylib`

Comment: All of my modules have the `*.module` file in the root projects (check [here](https://jitpack.io/com/github/hexworks/cobalt/2019.2.3-PREVIEW/build.log)) and I specify its id as the dependency. I also have the feature preview.

Comment: Btw if I add the `metadataSources` block to my project which uses the multiplatform dependency the build works, thanks.

Comment: @AdamArold, interestingly, I see that the POMs available on JitPack don't contain the Gradle module metadata marker `<!-- do_not_remove: published-with-gradle-metadata -->`, you can see that if you compare them with POMs published to a local Maven repo. Perhaps JitPack removes what it considers a comment from the POM? If that's the case, using a different Maven repo or making JitPack keep the marker should help.

Comment: That's super weird. This explains a lot! I'm gonna contact their support. Thanks for figuring this out!

Comment: To ignore indicator on pom file you can use ignoreGradleMetadataRedirection() method;
 metadataSources {
     mavenPom() 
     artifact()
     ignoreGradleMetadataRedirection() 
  }